# Get permission from Authorize Attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I've implemented my own `Authorize` attribute, and I notice that it queries to check permissions when I use `[Authorize]`.

Is there any way I can get that permission and use it in the current controller that applies the `Authorize` attribute without having to rewrite and requery the code in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you implemented your Authorize attribute as an ActionFilterAttribute you can use the ViewData collection to store information like this :

```
    public class RequireRegistrationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (request != null && 
            response != null)
        {
            bool isAuthenticated = request.IsAuthenticated;
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["IsAuthenticated"] = isAuthenticated;

            if (!isAuthenticated)
            {
                string url = String.Format(
                   "/?ReturnUrl={0}", 
                   HttpUtility.UrlEncode(request.Url.ToString()));
                response.Redirect(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the anoteated controller's acrion you can access the field with:

```
bool isAuthenticated = (bool)(ViewData["IsAuthenticated"] ?? false);
```