# Implementing object-level security with attributes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, actionfilterattribute

Is it possible to implement object-level security with a custom [`ActionFilterAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx)?

I read [Branislav Abadjimarinov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938835/get-permission-from-authorize-attribute/1946420#1946420) to [Get permission from Authorize Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1938835/196844) and started thinking about making an `AuthorizeAttribute`-like action filter for implementing object-level security.

Suppose I were to call it `ObjectAuthorizeAttribute` with the intended usage:

```
[ObjectAuthorize]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    //...
```

What would be the easiest way to access the ID value within `OnActionExecuting`?

Is something like this already available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the AuthorizeAttribute and have access to things like RouteData via the [AuthorizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizationcontext.aspx).  If you are doing authorization I think it makes more sense to start from the AuthorizeAttribute rather than ActionFilterAttribute.

```
var id = filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

Comment: I was wrong. Even though `Values` is a dictionary from strings to objects, `RouteData.Values["id"]` is still a string in my case even though I specify `int id` in the method signature. Regardless, your mentioning the `RouteData` property was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = filterContext.HttpContext.Request["id"];
```

Comment: This will work for Edit?id=1 but not for Edit/1, which is usually the same page in MVC.